# Git temporarily adding files to "commit" when switching branches - working with chokidar/node.js

Tags: node.js, git, gulp, file-watcher, chokidar

I'm creating a Node.js file watcher (with Chokidar, but it can work with Gulp as well). Every time I save my file, it does something with it, like passing JSHint.

But when I change branches, my watcher goes crazy and apply my functions to ALL files that have been changed between branches. So I've done a verification to check if my file is on the "to be committed" section from Git:

```
child_process.exec('cd '+ path +' && git status --porcelain', function (error, stdout, stderr) {...
```

I do a "git status" on my rep, parse the string and check the files to be committed. It's working so far.

BUT still when I change branches, Git temporarily adds d*ifferent files between branches* to the "to be committed" status, causing my code to still go crazy.

If I go on `cmd.exe` while my other branch is loading and type `git status` indeed it shows a ton of files changing, but it goes back to normal after it finishes.

I could check if the process "git.exe" is running on Task Manager, but it would be plus another verification (and this one takes way longer, because it list all tasklist processes):

```
child_process.exec('tasklist | find "git"', function (error, stdout, stderr) {...
```

Question: How can I check the Git files to be committed only on my current branch, even while switching branches?

Thanks!

Comment: Git uses *locking* to make sure that two different Git operations do not step on each other. In general, though, you are expected to wait for each Git operation to finish before starting another one; some operations, such as `git status` may either not bother to lock (because they are only reading), or may run in a read-only mode despite being unable to obtain the lock because some other Git operation holds it. If you are doing things asynchronously you may want to add your own locking as well.

Comment: And how could I what for this lock from Node? I'm checking if the .git/index.lock exists, but sometimes when Git is changing branches, for half a second it deletes and recreates the index.lock, and thats when my checking fails.

Comment: I have only a passing acquaintanceship with node.js and have no idea how, or whether, you can do this from there.